# An element-hiding script aimed to work in all pages of `facebook.com` works only in certain browser situations

Tags: javascript, facebook, userscripts

I have a script that does either `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, to various elements in all pages of `facebook.com`. I run it with Greasemonkey in Firefox and with Tampermonkey in Chrome. The end result is the same in both these browsers.

I am experiencing the following wired situation, that might has to do with facebook's usage of react.js.

### The problem:

1. If I just opened the browser in `about:blank` and navigated to facebook.com/page_2, the script WILL work.
2. If I'm in facebook.com/page_1 and opens facebook.com/page_2 **in a new tab**, the script WILL work on that page.

***BUT:***

- If I'm in facebook.com/page_1 and opens facebook.com/page_2 **in the same tab**, the script WILL NOT work on that page.
- If I'm in in the "Home" page (general wall page) and the script works (say, because I got there with way 1, or way 2), but then I click a peripheral link that links to that same page (say, the "Home" link in the main navigation bar), the page will be reloaded, but the script won't work this time.

---

### My question:

Do you know how to explain this behavior?

How could I combat it so that the script will always work?

### What I tried so far:

I tried to run it in a set interval, so that it will work each half a second and delete all content in all situations, but it doesn't help:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        facebook
// @namespace   nms
// @include     http://*.facebook.com/*
// @include     https://*.facebook.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

setInterval( ()=> {

// generalStuff:

    document.querySelectorAll(' #left_nav_section_nodes, .fbChatSidebar ').forEach( (e)=> {
        e.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

// myWall:

    document.querySelectorAll(' #stream_pagelet ').forEach( (e)=> {
        e.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

// People lists:

    // Friends list:

        document.querySelectorAll(' #pagelet_timeline_medley_friends, .friendBrowserForm, #u_jsonp_3_2e ').forEach( (e)=> {
            e.style.visibility = "hidden";
        });

    // PMYK:

        document.querySelectorAll(' #timeline_tab_content, #pagelet_pymk_timeline ').forEach( (e)=> {
            e.style.visibility = "hidden";
        });

// alert('All selectors are valid so far');

}, 500);
```

Comment: How do you use this script ?

Comment: I edited the question and detailed on this.

Comment: Where do you put this script ? Inside your console ?

Comment: No, it is executed in each page by GreaseMonkey/Tampermoneky.

Comment: since the page will constantly re-render parts and overwrite your overrides, you are much better off solving this via userstyles.org and a stylesheet. see https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/facebook